# Using FontAwesome radio buttons to download file when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a current setup that includes radio buttons that, when checked, depending on which radio button has been selected, will download the selected radios buttons file.

```
<input type="radio" name="download" id="x86"/>winrar x86 <br /> <input type="radio" name="download" id="x64"/>winrar x64 <br /> <input type="button" id="download" value="download"/>
```

```
var radio_x86 = document.getElementById('x86');
var radio_x64 = document.getElementById('x64');

var button = document.getElementById('download');

button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    if(radio_x86.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar500.exe");
    }else if(radio_x64.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-500.exe");
    } else {
        alert("Please check one of the options first.");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/2/)

However, I am wanting to stylize the radio buttons a little bit more using FontAwesome. This code can be used to apply FontAwesome to my radio buttons:

```
<label for="animal-kitty">
  <input type="radio" name="animal" id="animal-kitty" value="kitty" />
  <span>Option 1</span>
</label>
<label for="animal-doggie">
  <input type="radio" name="animal" id="animal-doggie" value="doggie" />
  <span>Option 2</span>
</label>
<label for="animal-fishie">
  <input type="radio" name="animal" id="animal-fishie" value="fishie" />
  <span>Option 3</span>
</label>
```

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-right: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777777;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: "\f10c";
  /* circle-blank */
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f058";
  /* circle */
}
```

[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8PYJg/426/)

The question: How can I combine these two, so that I can have stylized radio buttons and still have radio buttons that when selected will download a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy. Including needed resources and copying styles.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/19/)

[Do not repeat yourself version :)](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/22/)

```
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before,
input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-right: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: "\f10c"; /* circle-blank */
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* circle */
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* check-empty */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* check */
}
```

Comment: @Joshua Welcome! Also refactored your JS code. It might be useful for you)